# where is ro.boot.serialno and ro.serialno stored?

Tags: android, shell, configuration, administration, system-properties

Where is stored those 2 system properties?

Phone: THL W8s
Rom: W8s.JB2.FHD.EN.COM.16P256_MT6589TV1.0.3_20130815

The `ro.boot.serialno` should be changable with some recovery and from there is comming the `ro.serialno` and that value is displayed at: Settings->About phone->Status->Serial number for sure.

(I have lost the original serial number  with [Sp flash tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1982587) pressing the Format button)

**EDIT:**

```
/system/build.prop
```

Doesn't have this keys neither his values and it starts with:

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
```

Answer (score 5):

In my android version 4.2.2 `ro.serialno` and `ro.boot.serialno` can be stored in below file

[init/init.c line 663](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.2.2_r1/init/init.c#663)

Comment: At Least on 4.2.2, it appears that android reads ro.boot.serialno from the kernel cmdline arguments. `cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: Actually according to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.2.2_r1/init/init.c#642
cmdline argument needs to be androidboot.serialno

Comment: All the linked code in init.rc does is copy from one set of properties to another.  It does not initialize ro.boot.serialno but only copies whatever is already there to ro.serialno

Comment: If you look at the code starting at line 642 of the linked version of `init.c`.  you will see that kernel command line arguments that start with `androidboot.` are copied into readonly properties that start with `ro.boot.`.  The kernel command line argument named `androidboot.serialno` is set by u-boot (on my device anyway) by reading configuration fuses in the micro-controller which are set by the micro-controller manufacturer - the micro-controller's serial number.  That kernel command line argument becomes the `ro.boot.serialno` property.

Comment: You can see the kernel command line with: `adb shell cat /proc/cmdline`